# Should Rspec file structure match file structure of code being tested?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a gem. I want to test some of the classes. I have them in modules.

The file structure:

```
my_gem
  /lib
    /my_gem
      /practices
        /texas
          /medical_practice.rb
```

medical_practice.rb:

```
module MyGem
  module Practices
    module Texas
      class MedicalPractice < Practice            
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my spec directory, should I follow the same structure?

```
spec
  /practices
    /texas
      /medical_practice_spec.rb
```

Or is it best practice to place medical_practice_spec.rb right under the /spec directory?

Comment: yeah it's a good idea to split it up into hierarchical folders. If you keep everything 'flat' (e.g. at the same level of folder nesting) it will grow way too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In my spec directory, should I follow the same structure?

Yes.

Usually in RSpec the spec structure matches the directory structure of the files under test.

Another example (when using Rails):

`spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb` would test `app/controllers/users_controller.rb`

Comment: Could be worth pointing to a source, and further reading too. Like this one: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/directory-structure